# Kernel dies during downloading sec-edgar files

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook and **sec_edgar_downloader** package for downloading **10-K** and
**10-Q**  [SEC files](https://sec.report/). There are some CIK-s that kernel dies during downloading their files. I checked RAM, but it was OK, I think it is because of recursion limit. Is it enable to skip it with `try` and `except` or with other method?

I am using this code:

```
`from sec_edgar_downloader import Downloader`
 dl = Downloader()
 for i in cik_list:
    for j in ["10-K","10-Q"]:
        dl.get(j, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your RAM while you download it ? It could be the reason why your kernel dies.

Comment: yes I checked, it was 30% in use. I think the problem is recurssion limit